# CKEditor: How to change the main content area's padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

Is there any way to change the main content area's padding (**per instance basis**)? I am looking into the skins css files and still haven't got any clues.

Thanks in advance!

**Edited**

I found `content.css` but if I'm not wrong, it applies to all instances.

Answer (score 1):

In content.css I changed body CSS to include:

```
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
```

This didn't work initially, even after re-publishing (Visual Studio 2010) and checking the file. But then figures that some CSS changes haven't always worked - so after clearing Browser (Chrome 36.0) Cache - It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, a little bit trouble but it should work:

1. Duplicate file ../ckeditor/contents.css as ../ckeditor/contents_xxx.css
2. Add following code to contents_xxx.css, 20px just for example:

   body {padding: 20px;}
3. Edit ../ckeditor/ckeditor.js

   a. Search and replace: 'contents.css' -> cssFile

   b. Add following code to the top of ckeditor.js:

   var cssFile = 'contents.css';
   if(document.URL.indexOf("THE_URL_WHICH_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_ADD_PADDING") > -1){
       cssFile = 'contents_XXX.css';
   }

*Please update "THE_URL_WHICH_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_ADD_PADDING".

Comment: @ahgood .. I tried to remove the padding (padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;) but it is not working.

Comment: Can you please paste the code you've changed here? CSS and JS.

Comment: body
{
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px; 
 color: #222; 
 background-color: #fff; 
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

Comment: In fact, I didn't changed anything in ckeditor.js. I just tried out in content.css itself first.

Comment: if you only want to apply the padding for one instance(or one page), you will have to update ckeditor.js.

Comment: @ahgood ... yeah i got your point but the css is not even working for all instances in the first place ... Do you have any idea?

Comment: i didn't get your point..you mean 1 page may have several editor box and you do only want to apply for one of them?

Comment: Yes ... what you just said is right .. but before i do this for a particular instance ... i just tried it out for all instances ... just to make sure that the css is working fine ... if it is working fine for all instances ... i can proceed to make it for one instance

Comment: If you just want to make sure, try this: 1. Open your webpage which contains the editor; 2. copy and paste following code to browser address bar, then press Enter key. javascript:frames[0].document.body.style.padding='20px';void(0)

Comment: I think the padding is outside the frame 0 because I can see the padding outside the blue border. javascript:frames[0].document.body.style.padding='0px';frames[0].document.body.style.border="1px solid blue";void(0)

Comment: Try to update margin for body tag then: javascript:frames[0].document.body.style.margin='0px';void(0)

Comment: Yeah .. it is working ... how should i include it nicely in the code?

Comment: back to your original question, you do want to apply to whole site OR one page OR one editor in a page?

Comment: There are multiple instances on the same page. I want to apply this style to a few instances only.